# How to filter/search Element UI table with separate JS function

Tags: vue.js, vuejs2

I'm building a Element table in Vue (https://element.eleme.io/#/en-US/component/table) The table needs to have a search block that will filter the rows as you enter text into it. If the search block text appears in any of 2-3 columns it needs to show that row. The example provided does this only for one column(name).

```
<el-table
    :data="tableData.filter(data => !search || data.name.toLowerCase().includes(search.toLowerCase()))"
    style="width: 100%">
```

How can I break out the code to make it a separate function that I can add for multiple columns?

Comment: You can detach `filters` and receive parameters in that `filters` and use them in common.

Please refer to the document.
https://vuejs.org/v2/guide/filters.html

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Have you tried this way?

**Methods**

```
methods: {
 searchData(dataTable, query) {
   return dataTable.filter(data => !search || `data.${query}.toLowerCase().includes(search.toLowerCase())`)
 }
}
```

**Table**

```
<el-table
    :data="searchData(tableData, name)" // attach your query here
    style="width: 100%">
```

Comment: I ended up not using the second parameter and just string along all filters inside one function as I know what columns will be filtered on.